# Copy data entry the form and print out a separate file in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have problem copying data from the list into the form in google sheet .
My explanation is below

The first step  :On the orderlist sheet copy the data and paste it into the Purchase order　sheet.
(There is a case of 1 line list or 2 line)

The second step :Data entered in Purchase order sheet will print out a separate file.
*For example, the order list has 30 orders, I have to repeat 30 times.
Is there a way to solve my problem

[This is  purchase order sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15IL5_82xZ7Uln99tEUIl6VUelVr7r438-VOW9Qhe4aU/edit?usp=sharing)

[This is order list sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XpyumYopURKhdt_GzEWuvqZF6_AR5YjZXo_R_Z6gyZM/edit?usp=sharing)

[explanation video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UogBw-5wJ--uU9QKyTTpX2IgPkcDZC9Q/view?usp=sharing)

```
function myFunction() {
var ss_data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1XpyumYopURKhdt_GzEWuvqZF6_AR5YjZXo_R_Z6gyZM");
var ss_data_value= ss_data.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getA1Notation("A2:T18").getvalue();
var destination= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Purchase order")
for(var i=0;i<=ss_data_value.lenght;i++){
```

}

}

thank for your help

Comment: In your situation, what filename do you want to give to the created PDF file? And, in your situation, when the tasks are looped, I think that creating the PDF file to the Google Drive might be suitable. How about this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Thank you for reply .Of course PDF OK.`, I cannot still obtain the answer for my question. If you cannot understand about my English, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike thank for reply i want create PDF file names by date for example 2021/05/07_1;2021/05/07_1 ...

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying of `i want create PDF file names by date for example 2021/05/07_1;2021/05/07_1 ...`, I couldn't understand about your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. You want to create the files with the same filenames for all files?

Comment: @Tanaike i so sorry it wrong . It's like that 2021/05/07_1;2021/05/07_2; 2021/05/07_3;2021/05/07_4;...

Comment: ＠tanaike 
you can tell me how can coding that please?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `you can tell me how can coding that please?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to think of the solution. I apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanaike Can you solve my problem?　⇒《　Copy data entry the form and print out a separate file in Google Sheet　》

Comment: Hi there @HiepAnh! I can't understand your end goal, could you please modify your question to clarify it? Also, where are the PDF files that you want to rename? Do you want to rename them to `2021/05/07_1`, `2021/05/07_2`, `2021/05/07_3`…? Or do you want to do it based on the actual date like `{YEAR}/{MONTH}/{DAY}_{INCREMENTAL}`?

Comment: Hi, @Jacques-GuzelHeron my ultimate goal is to want to save the file as a pdf with a date attached. I also attach the video please watch it before commenting

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `@Tanaike If you can not solve my problem please Don't say anything`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering the question and its explanatory files I understand that you want to copy new rows from a Form response Sheet into a different Sheet. Later you want to download that second Sheet as a PDF. If my understanding of your question is correct, then you can reach your goals effortlessly by continuing developing with Apps Script.

First of all you want to use an [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger that fires every time that the Form response Sheet is modified. This means that every time that the Form receives a response, the trigger will run. There are two main operations that should be run inside the trigger script; first you could use the trigger [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) to save into a `var` the contents of the new row. Secondly that row should be moved to the *purchase Sheet* using a tool like [`Range.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues). At this point the new Form responses are programmatically added to the desired Sheet.

Now for the second part of the question let's download that Sheet as a PDF. There is a straightforward way of doing it by using [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app). I have copied below a sample approach that creates a PDF from the Sheet and drops it on Drive, but you can tweak it to configure the transfer at your will. Please ask me any doubts about this answer.

```js
function sheet2PDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  DriveApp.createFile(spreadsheet.getBlob());
}
```